# Define null value meaning global?

Tags: mysql, database-design, null

I have created a `website_settings` table. Is it bad practice to have `website_id` as `null` which mean this `key` is applied to any website, in other Global?

For example:

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------+---------+
| id | client_id | website_id | key                          | value         | is_json |
+----+-----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------+---------+
|  7 |         1 | NULL       | display_featured_products    | 1             |       0 |
|  9 |         1 | NULL       | display_popular_products     | 1             |       0 |
| 10 |         1 | 1          | categories_display_mode      | across        |       0 |
| 11 |         1 | 2          | categories_display_mode      | across        |       0 |
| 12 |         1 | 3          | categories_display_mode      | single        |       0 |
| 13 |         1 | NULL       | categories_id                | ["3","5","6"] |       1 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------------------------+---------------+---------+
```

You can also see I have repeated key of `categories_display_mode` and website_id is not null.

Edit: Fixed id column to be unique

Comment: Your table as posted here doesn't seem to have a key. If that's the case then it's definitely not good practice. Was website_id originally supposed to be a key attribute? It looks like you possibly haven't identified a non-key dependency here that ought to belong in another table. If you fixed that by creating another table then maybe you don't need this nullable column.

Comment: @sqlvogel I don't understand what do you mean by table don't have a key. You can see a `key` field next to `website_id`. You can see @Bill Karwin answered my question and he understood what I meant.

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand what a key is. The column you have called "key" is clearly not a key because its values are not unique in this table. If there is a key of this table then you haven't shown it in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `website_id` permit nulls means that this column cannot be part of a key for this table (key columns are required to be non-nullable).

If we look at the other columns in the table:

```
id, client_id, key, value, is_json
```

we can see that some values in these columns are duplicated:

```
| 10 |         1 | categories_display_mode      | across        |       0 |
| 10 |         1 | categories_display_mode      | across        |       0 |
```

There is no candidate key present at all. So there seems to be something wrong with your proposed design.

From what you have said, I expect there is some non-key dependency between `website_id` and `key`. If you apply the principle of 5th Normal Form I think that one or both of those columns ought to be in another table and **NOT** nullable. Conclusion: on the basis of the information here I think it's the wrong thing to do to make `website_id` nullable.

Comment: My mistake, I was copying a few rows here on stackoverflow and I forgot to update the ID to be unique

Comment: Fine. So it looks like you have a non-key dependency involving client_id, website_id, key. That's something you could remedy by creating another table for "global" settings instead of making website_id nullable.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is used in different ways in SQL.

One of these meanings for NULL is for an **inapplicable value,** like the "date of termination" for an employee who is still employed.

Using NULL in your case to signify that the key applies to any/all websites is a reasonable use of NULL. It's better than trying to assign some "special value" like 0 or -999 for that purpose.

Comment: Do you agree with @sqlvogel above?

Comment: Yes, your `id` column has duplicates, so it can't be the primary key of the table by itself. It can't be combined with `website_id` to be the primary key, because primary key columns are required to be NOT NULL.

Comment: Oops, that was my mistake. I was copying and pasting the rows here and make changes on other fields value.

Comment: Well, you should understand our reaction at least! :-)

Comment: he said `key` rather than `primary key` - it would understood him :)

Comment: I think sqlvogel used the term key in a standard way.  If a table has no key, it follows that it has no primary key.  What part of "key" didn't you understand?

Comment: @WalterMitty, in MySQL, "key" and "index" are synonyms. A table can definitely have no primary key, yet still have one or more secondary indexes (but of course this is not recommended). Sqlvogel may have been using "key" in the relational theoretical usage, as in [candidate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Bill.  I find it hard to reconcile "key" and "index" being synonyms with everything I learned thirty years ago.  If terminology continues to splinter this way, pretty soon no one will be able to coach newbies except for people using the very same tool.

Comment: The authors of MySQL don't know what a key is and possibly if they knew a bit more about databases they would have produced a better product. I'd like to think that the users of MySQL generally *do* know what a key is.

Comment: @sqlvogel, well said! I take it *you* have developed a superior RDBMS product, used successfully by 75% of the websites on earth?